# Simple client/server library

Tags: clojure, socket

I'm writing a Tamagotchi clone, and decided to try making an online version. Since I don't do a lot of networking projects, I decided to try and go off on a tangent and screw around with sockets and making basic generic functions. I ended up with an ***extremely*** basic set of functions that I'm going to make use of later. I'd like to have them looked over first.

Really, I'm looking for any critique here; this is going to be a very open, general review. Any small thing you notice would be appreciated.

A couple things I'd like to know though:

- How much of an abuse my use of `clojure.async`? I'm using it for 2 reasons:

  1. So messages can be printed between threads without any interleaving.
  2. To make use of its thread pool. I have terrible experiences with managing thread pools. They always seem to insist on keeping the JVM running long after the program has exited, regardless of what measures I try to end them. `async` doesn't seem to have this problem though.
- Is there a better way of implementing my "message queue" system? It's mainly for testing, so messages can be logged from different threads in the pool without being printed interleaved with each other.

Here's an example of it's use. The server sends a random number to the client, waits for a response, then terminates the connection. I have the library tucked away inside the `net-helpers` namespace:

Server:

```
(ns net.rand-num-test.server-test
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.core.async :refer [chan]]

            [helpers.net-helpers :as nh])

  (:import [java.net ServerSocket Socket]
           [java.io IOException]))

(def msg-q (chan 10))
(nh/start-message-loop msg-q)

(defn q
  "(q)ueue's the message to be printed."
  [& msgs]
  (apply nh/queue-message msg-q msgs))

(defn random-num-sender
  "Accepts a client, sends them a random number, then waits for a response."
  [^Socket client]
  (let [n (str (- (rand-int 100) 50))]
    (with-open [c client]
      (q "Accepted a connection from" (nh/pretty-address c)
         "\nSent" n "from thread" (.getId (Thread/currentThread)))

      (nh/write c n)

      (let [response (nh/read-line c)]
        (q "Recieved:" response)))))

(defn simple-error-handler [server-sock exception]
  (do
    (q (.getMessage exception))
    (.close server-sock)))

(defn async-rand-num-server
"Start the server on the given port"
[port]
  (nh/start-async-server port random-num-sender simple-error-handler))
```

Client:

```
(ns net.rand-num-test.client-test
  (:require [helpers.net-helpers :as nh]
            [clojure.core.async :refer [chan thread]])

  (:import [java.net Socket]))

(def msg-q (chan 10))

(nh/start-message-loop msg-q)

(defn test-connect-f [^Socket server-sock]
  (let [rec (nh/read-line server-sock)]
    (nh/queue-message msg-q "Received:" rec)
    (Thread/sleep 2000)

    (nh/write server-sock rec)
    (nh/queue-message msg-q "Wrote: " rec)))

(defn simple-connection []
  (nh/connect-to "localhost" 5555 test-connect-f))

(defn async-connect-many
  "Spam the server with many requests all at once."
  [n]
  (doseq [m (range n)]
    (thread (simple-connection))))
```

And the library in question:

```
(ns helpers.net-helpers
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [read-line])

  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.core.async :refer [thread <! >!! go-loop]])

  (:import [java.io BufferedWriter BufferedReader IOException]
           [java.net Socket ServerSocket]))

(defn start-message-loop
  "Takes a channel, and starts a go-loop that prints each message sequentially.
  Stops when the channel is closed."
  [msg-chan]
  (go-loop []
    (let [[f-msg :as msgs] (<! msg-chan)]
      (when f-msg
        (apply println msgs)
        (recur)))))

(defn queue-message
  "Similar to println, except can be used across threads without causing interleaving.
  The msg-chan is expected to be a channel that was previously given to start-message-loop."
  [msg-chan & messages]
  (>!! msg-chan messages))

(defn write
  "Writes the message to the socket.
  Terminates the message with a newline, then flushes the stream."
  [^Socket sock ^String message]
  (let [^BufferedWriter w (io/writer sock)
        nl-terminated-ms (str message "\n")]

    (.write w nl-terminated-ms)
    (.flush w)))

(defn read-line
  "Reads a line from the socket."
  [^Socket sock]
  (let [^BufferedReader r (io/reader sock)]
    (.readLine r)))

; FIXME: Expect connect-f to close sock when done like with server, or use with-open?
(defn connect-to
  "Opens a socket for the given address and port, and passes it to connect-f.
   Closes the socket."
  [^String address ^long port connect-f]
  (with-open [server-sock (Socket. address port)]
    (connect-f server-sock)))

(defn pretty-address
  "Returns the host name of a socket."
  [^Socket sock]
  (.getHostAddress (.getInetAddress sock)))

(defn start-simple-server
  "Opens a single-threaded server on the given port, and accepts clients.
  Each client socket is handed to accept-f. Expects accept-f to close the given client.
  In the event of an error, error-handler will be given the server socket and exception.
  If the server socket is closed, the accept-loop will end."
  [port accept-f error-handler]
  (let [ss (ServerSocket. port)]
    (while (not (.isClosed ss))
      (try
        (let [^Socket client (.accept ss)]
          (accept-f client))

        (catch IOException e
          (error-handler ss e))))))

(defn start-async-server
  "Same as start-simple-server, but each accept-f is run in a thread pool."
  [port accept-f error-handler]
  (let [async-accept-handler #(thread (accept-f %))]
    (start-simple-server port async-accept-handler error-handler)))
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `read-line` method ended up being kind of broken. It creates a new buffer for every line read, so data is lost. I ended up creating a `BufferedSocket` record that maintains a BufferedReader`.